# How to create a Custom Field on "Message" (crmmessage) and "File" record types in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite

Is it possible to create custom fields on NetSuite "Message" (crmmessage) and "File" record types? NetSuite Record browser is showing that "Message" and "File" record types support custom fields, but I cannot find a way using which I can create.

[image: File]

[image: Message]

I also checked in "Customization  >>  Lists, Records, & Fields  >>  Other Record Fields", but only supported record types appearing there are:

Account
Address
Automatic Location Assignment Configuration
Automatic Location Assignment Rule
Bin
Campaign Event
Class
Competitor
Department
Domain
Expense Category
Format Profile
Item Location Configuration
Item Source
Location
Note
Promotion Code
Region
Role
Subsidiary
Subsidiary Settings
Tax Code
Vendor-Subsidiary Relationship
Workflow
Workplace

No "Message" and "File" record is listed there.

Any idea if custom fields are really supported in "Message" and "File" record type or that's just mistakenly written in Record Browser.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did a ton of digging and I do not believe the `Message` or `File` records support custom fields.

The record browser is likely incorrect.